# How to populate data frame based on previous row values with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation, imputation

I have the following dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "id": ['a', 'd'],
    "amount": [3000, 4000],
    "rate": [0.2, 0.3],
    "date": ["2022-07-21", "2022-08-11"],
    "months": [4, 5],
})
```

I want to create installments for the given trades. Output should look like this:

```
  id    interest   principal        date       balance  installment
0  a   50.000000  731.508250  2022-07-21  2.268492e+03   781.508250
1  a   37.808196  743.700055  2022-08-21  1.524792e+03   781.508250
2  a   25.413195  756.095055  2022-09-21  7.686966e+02   781.508250
3  a   12.811611  768.696640  2022-10-21  0.00000        781.508250
4  d  100.000000  760.987444  2022-08-11  3.239013e+03   860.987444
5  d   80.975314  780.012130  2022-09-11  2.459000e+03   860.987444
6  d   61.475011  799.512433  2022-10-11  1.659488e+03   860.987444
7  d   41.487200  819.500244  2022-11-11  8.399877e+02   860.987444
8  d   20.999694  839.987750  2022-12-11  0.00000        860.987444
```

Key point here is that the next row values depend on previous `balance` value. The first time `balance` is `amount` of the source data frame.

My current solution:

```py
import numpy_financial as npf
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "id": ['a', 'd'],
    "amount": [3000, 4000],
    "rate": [0.2, 0.3],
    "date": ["2022-07-21", "2022-08-11"],
    "months": [4, 5],
})


def get_output_df(df):
    columns = ["id", "interest", "principal", "date", "balance"]
    output_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        rate = row["rate"] / 12
        months = row["months"]
        amount = row["amount"]
        date = pd.to_datetime(row["date"]).date()
        installment_amount = npf.pmt(rate=rate, nper=months, pv=-amount)
        prior_balance = amount

        loan_installment_data = []
        for i in range(months):
            interest_amount = rate * prior_balance
            principal_amount = installment_amount - interest_amount
            balance = prior_balance - principal_amount

            loan_installment_data.append(
                {
                    "id": row["id"],
                    "interest": interest_amount,
                    "principal": principal_amount,
                    "date": date,
                    "installment": installment_amount,
                    "balance": balance
                }
            )

            prior_balance = balance
            date += relativedelta(months=1)

        output_df = output_df.append(loan_installment_data, ignore_index=True)
    return output_df


output_df = get_output_df(df)
```

Is there any pandas feature i could use to do the same implementation?

Comment: Did you manage to implement my answer using `shift(1)`?

Comment: No. I have `balance` depending on `principal` and `prior_balance`, and I have `interest` depending on prior_balance too. And all of these parameters are populated over time.
I couldn't find any pandas feature or formula to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [pandas `shift` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html), which shifts row values by the value specified (so can be previous row). By using `shift`, you can have the previous row's amount for example available to the next row, and do your calculations without looping through each row and saving each previous value in a temporary variable.

Here is an example with your data:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "id": ['a', 'd'],
    "amount": [3000, 4000],
    "rate": [0.2, 0.3],
    "date": ["2022-07-21", "2022-08-11"],
    "months": [4, 5],
})

df["prior_balance"] = df["amount"].shift(1, fill_value=0)
df
```

Output:

[image: output of code above]

Using `shift`, the first row would be a NaN, so you can use `fill_value=0` to set that NaN value to 0 as there is no previous amount for example.

Comment: Even better, `shift` has a `fill_value` parameter. `.shift(fill_value=0)` This will also keep an integer column from converting to floats, so you don't need to call `.astype(int)` either!